# Manipulate CSV when the number of column are unknown

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to capture data from different pages..I make an `array` of it and then I write cvs file using PHP ( for the moment, I am planning the things)..

Now issue is, if `array` contains always same number of elements, thats really simple, like

```
sku
asin
name
size
```

creating `CSV` using this struture is simple, but How will I create CSV when I got a structure like

```
sku
asin
name
size
size-1
size-2
...
....
size-n
```

where n is not constant and holds different values in different pages..

, in some cases, it could be 4, in other cases, it could be 8, and in some cases,it can be zero( no size is available)

in first case, when columns are know, CSV will be

sku  asin  name  size

and in second case, CSV will be

```
SKU asin name size size size-1 (first element)
SKU asin name size size size-1 size-2   size-3  size-4  size-5(second element)
SKU asin name size size (third element)
SKU asin name size size size-1 size-2   size-3  size-4  size-5 size-6 size-8(second element)
```

- Its not sure that how many total number of columns will be there..
- it is not sure that how many number of column will aprear for each
  row

**An ugly situation..**

what will happen if I got following row to be written in CSV

```
SKU asin name size size size-1 size-2   size-3  size-4  size-5 size-6 size-8(second element)
sku-v asin-v (No value for name, size, size-1) size-2-v nothing for rest of columns

where v stands for value
```

How can I write a CSV file in this case?? How will manage columns in this case?

I tried thinking a lot on it, but cant find a way out..

can somebody help me?

thanks..

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Programmers. Please don't crosspost questions. Have a pleasant day.

Comment: I don't think csv is the format you want to use for this if avoidable...

Comment: so, what would be correct format for this?

Comment: Are you trying to create a two dimensional array by [page][element]?

Comment: no, It will one dimensional array

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to be able to figure out how many columns a row has?

What about

```
sku
asin
name
size
NUMBER_OF_SIZE_COLUMNS
size-1
size-2
...
....
size-n
```

Alternatively there may be a way to deduce the number of columns from the `skun, asin, name, size` columns?

Comment: to be true, I am not getting you at all, what I want is, I got unknown number of columns, and I want to write csv from that